# How to read all assets from assets folder

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to programatically access the assets folder and loop over all its content?

I want to display all my assets for something like an emoji picker.

I tried searching the web for a solution but all the answers was for a single file from assets.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Hope you get the answer!

the flutter compiler lists all files from these folders in the AssetManifest.json file. All we have to do is read this file:

```
final manifestJson = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('AssetManifest.json');
final images = json.decode(manifestJson).keys.where((String key) => key.startsWith('assets/images'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a restriction in the early stage of flutter i guess. But now you can add/read all assets.
In the  `pubspec.yaml` file include the whole folder with `/`

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

[official docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#specifying-assets)

Programatically you can acces, you should pass/use the asset's name dynamically in that case. There are lots of packages are available for emoji, I think that will be better to use one of them.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but i wasnt talking about it. I was talking about progrmaticly access the folder that holds all the assets and loop over it. In you example, it means to get the path to the assets folder and loop over all its content

Answer (score 0):

For accessing single file we can do by file include pubspec.yaml folder with /:

> flutter:
>     assets:
>       - assets/res/my_file.txt

And For access all assets from asset folder :

> flutter:
>     assets:
>       - assets/

Comment: Thank you for your time, but i wasnt declaring it in the yml.  I was talking about progrmaticly access the folder that holds all the assets and loop over it. In you example, it means to get the path to the assets folder and loop over all its content